# Where to find openmpi-doc on my ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: mpi

I installed openmpi by `apt-get install openmpi-doc`. I think it is some folder that contain the document on openmpi? where can I find it?
I just switched from Windows to Bbuntu, so a lot of things are difficult for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `man` to read manual pages:

`man openmpic`

Try `man man`. ;)

I you want to know the location of your man pages, use `manpath`.